# I have an XML of a base class instance, want to deserialize to derived class instance

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, derived-class, base-class

I have an XML of an instance of a base class, and I want to deserialize it and end up with an instance of a derived class The property that is not in the base class would be set to default.

My example classes look like this:

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
    public int MyProperty1 { get; set; }
}

public class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public int MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

My attempt at serializing an instance of MyBaseClass and then deserializing looks like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyBaseClass myBaseClass = new MyBaseClass() { MyProperty1 = 1 };
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyBaseClass));
        string xml = Serialize(myBaseClass, serializer);
        MyDerivedClass myDerivedClass = Deserialize(serializer, xml);
    }

    private static string Serialize(MyBaseClass myBaseClass, XmlSerializer serializer)
    {
        using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, new XmlWriterSettings()))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, myBaseClass);
            }
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }
    }

    private static MyDerivedClass Deserialize(XmlSerializer serializer, string xml)
    {
        using (StringReader textReader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(textReader, new XmlReaderSettings()))
            {
                var deserialized =  (MyBaseClass)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
                return (MyDerivedClass)deserialized;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This of course fails in the cast to MyDerivedClass in the last line (can't downcast), but how would I go about fixing it? Can I do something in the Deserialization to say that it should end up as another class?

(I would like to avoid writing a Copy method that copies each property, because in my real code I have many properties in the base class.)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @Stormcloak's answer below -- don't use a serializer, use [tag:automapper] -- would seem to be the best approach.  However there are a couple of tricks for doing this with `XmlSerializer`.  Still need to know?

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast base class to derived class like that. The simplest way to perform it using `AutoMapper` or you can create a constructor for `MyDerivedClass`;

```
public class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public MyDerivedClass()
    {

    }

    public MyDerivedClass(MyBaseClass b)
    {
        MyProperty1 = b.MyProperty1;
    }

    public int MyProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

And return like this;

```
var deserialized = (MyBaseClass)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
return new MyDerivedClass(deserialized);
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answers. Automapper looked like overkill for me, so I did this by modifying my XML using XmlDocument: I created a new XmlDocument with MyDerivedClass as top node, and then imported everything under the MyBaseClass top node from the original XML string. Not a general solution, but worked for me where I know what classes I am using.